# Cannot start Windows phone Emulator. Windows phone Emulator requires Hyper - v. My laptop is core 2 duo, windows 8.1 64bit, 4 gb ram

Tags: windows, windows-phone, hyper-v

Cannot start Windows phone Emulator. Windows phone Emulator requires Hyper -  v. 
My laptop is core 2 duo, windows 8.1 64 bit, 4 GB ram.
Kindly help me I am a new win. phone developer.

Comment: Core 2 Duo does not support SLAT (Second Level Address Translation), which is required for Hyper-V. Since your machine does not support Hyper-V, which is what the emulator runs on, you cannot use the emulator.

Comment: You can still debug on a device.

Comment: you can also install the windows phone 7 sdk